Matlab provides a solution for a system without solutions
I want to solve a linear system in 3 variables Ax=b where A is a 4x3 matrix and b is a vector.
A is the matrix A=[1 1 1 ; 1 2 1 ; 1 2 3 ; 1 4 1] while b=[1 1 1 2]
The complete 4x4 matrix A|b has rank 4:
> rank([A b'])
ans = 4


so the system has no solution.
I used linsolve:
> linsolve(A,b')
ans =

   0.6071
   0.3571
  -0.1071


which is nonsense from a mathematical point of view, given that Ax=b has no solutions!
The only thing I can imagine,  is that the software is providing a least-square solution for the system, that is a solution of A'Ax=A'b; in fact you get
> linsolve(A'*A,A'*b')
ans =

   0.6071
   0.3571
  -0.1071


yet it doesn't warn me about this: it provides the solution linsolve(A,b') as if it were an actual solution, which it isn't!
Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

You're right, it should be clearer in the documentation for linsolve. The documentation for mldivide actually states that If A is a rectangular m-by-n matrix with m ~= n, and B is a matrix with m rows, then A\B returns a least-squares solution to the system of equations A*x= B. x may not be the minimum-norm solution

You can log bugs and enhancement requests for MATLAB here: https://supportcases.mathworks.com/mwsupport/s/casetypeselection?language=en_US&c__caseParameter=productusage&s_tid=srlp_product, might be worth reporting formally so this behaviour can at least be addressed in the documentation

The linsolve documentation says “When A is square, linsolve uses LU factorization with partial pivoting.
For all other cases, linsolve uses QR factorization with column pivoting.” I guess they expect people to know that QR factorization leads to a least squares solution? MATLAB documentation is usually great, but this time it dropped the ball. :/

@CrisLuengo I expect that any software that says "I solve a linear system" just does exactly that, which has a very precise and well established meaning. So if a linear system does not have a solution, I expect exactly that answer: "This system does not have a solution". In case it is so smart as to provide an "approximated solution", wathever that means, or a least square solution, I expect it to just say so! You may ask for a solution for something in real life upon which depend lives! I am really astonished that a software so famous (and expensive!) such as Matlab behaves in such a poor way

Since the A has more rows than columns, it is an overdetermined system, meaning that the number of equations is greater than the number of unknowns. It generally has no solution*.
linsolve outputs a solution that minimizes the error, i.e., the norm of (b'-A*x). This is the best "MATLAB" can do. Numpy's numpy.linalg also does the same.
Behind the scene MATLAB uses the Method of Least Squares with Euclidean norm for the norm of this error. This is what linsolve(A'*A,A'*b'), as you wrote, does. Or equivalently,lsqr(A,b')will output the same answer.
*Note: This error will be 0 if the rank is the same as the number of variables, but it is not the case here. For example, an overdetermined system of A=[1 1 1 ; 1 2 1 ; 1 2 3 ; 1 1 1] and b = [1 1 1 1] has the solution of [1 0 0].' (as outputted by linsolve(A,b'),linsolve(A'*A,A'*b') and lsqr(A,b')).
